# Three tables join in SQL

Tags: sql, join, inner-join

I am newbie in SQL. I want to join three tables in SQL. Below is my query, please check and correct me where I am wrong -

Tables:

- CARD: ID,Code,Name,CC
- PGM: ID,Code
- PGMeCode: ID,Code,CC

Query:

```
Select *
FROM CARD
INNER JOIN PGMeCode PGMeCode.Code = CARD.Code AND PGMeCode.CC = CARD.CC
INNER JOIN PGM PGM.Code = Card.Code
WHERE Card.ID = 'SomeThing'
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong. Please suggest me!!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

You are missing the keyword `ON`, placed after the table name.

```
INNER JOIN tablename ON condition...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM CARD INNER JOIN PGMeCode ON PGMeCode.Code = CARD.Code AND PGMeCode.CC = CARD.CC INNER JOIN PGM ON PGM.Code = Card.Code WHERE Card.ID = 'SomeThing';
```

Try this query